How does a 4 node+witness WSFC cluster handle outage of 2 nodes including the WSFC owner
I have a WSFC cluster with two nodes in DC1, two nodes in DC2, and a fileshare witness in DC3, with each node having one vote.
The WSFC owner/current host server is one of the nodes in DC1. If DC1 suffers a network outage taking down both nodes, in theory the quorum should be kept because this setup can tolerate two simultaneous node failures.
However in actuality I am observing quorum loss from a scenario where:

DC1 loses connectivity to DC3 (connection between DC1-DC2 and DC3-DC3 is maintained). The WSFC owner detects that the fileshare witness in DC3 is unable to arbitrate.
DC1 loses connectivity to DC2. Now DC1 only sees two votes in the cluster so it loses quorum.
Even though DC2-DC3 connectivity remains, it still believes that DC3 is unable to arbitrate from the reading in (1) and also loses quorum.

Even though DC2 and DC3 are operating normally (combined 3 vote count), quorum was lost when DC1 networking went down.
Is quorum supposed to be kept in this scenario?
